# PHP Array Delete Element or Subtract

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values [20,40,30,50] and I have another variable with value 30.

I need to subtract 30 from the first element.
And if $var is greater then need to delete the first element and subtract remaining value from next element in the array.

Example: 
$arr = array(20,40,30,50);
$var = 30;

The result array should be (30,30,50)

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your attempts so far.

Comment: @tftd why would it? See it as four bank accounts why would one increase? Never happened to me at least. Always negative numbers on my accounts

Comment: @Andreas actually never mind... I read it from a mobile and it didn't make sense to me at the time. :)

Comment: @Andreas Your code works! Thank you

Comment: Code of The fourth bird and scotty86 is also works well :)

Comment: @Rahul Shrivastava Your code is not working for some values. If $var = 10, it is not working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array and subtract and/or unset values accordingly.

```
$arr = [20,40,30,50];
$var =30;

Foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    If($var > $val){
        $var -= $val;
        Unset($arr[$key]);
    }Else{
        $val -= $var;
        $var = 0;
    }
}
Unset($val);
Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/vJN2o

You can add this line `If($var>0) Echo $var;` too see if there is anything remaing in the $var when the loop ends.
https://3v4l.org/LU2Tf

Updated links to include $var =0;

Comment: True again @Nigel. Thanks!

Comment: it will not produce expected out put

Comment: @RahulShrivastava can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you want to delete the item from the array if the item minus the `$var` is lower than zero. Then continue with the rest value for the rest of the array items.

Try it like this:

```
$values = [20,40,30,50];
$var = 30;

foreach ($values as $key => &$value) {
    if ($value - $var > 0) {
        $value -= $var;
        // There is nothing more to subtract so break.
        break;
    }
        unset($values[$key]);
        // Turn the var into a positive value so we can continue
        $var = -1 * ($value - $var);
}
print_r($values);
```

[Demo with 30](https://3v4l.org/uUAe3)

[Demo with 5](https://3v4l.org/0RLGF)

Answer (score -2):

Recursion incoming!

```
function array_sub($arr, $sub) {
    if(count($arr) <= 0) {
        return array();
    }

    $arr[0] -= $sub;

    if($arr[0] > 0) {
        return $arr;
    }
    else {
        $sub = array_shift($arr) * (-1);
        return array_sub($arr, $sub);
    }
}

$arr = array(20,40,30,50);
$sub = 30;
$arr = array_sub($arr, $sub);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 30 [2] => 50 )
```